# When suggesting edits, link to review does not appear on suggested tag wiki edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

When you perform an edit on a normal post, a notice appears to show that your edit has been placed in the review queue:

[image: Thanks for your edit! This edit will be visible only to you]

This notice contains a link to the review item, so you can track its progress.

However the notice that appears when you edit a tag wiki or excerpt does not contain this link:

[image: Same text, no link]

**Can a link to the review item please be added to the notice?**